# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7fc6f1b92240>

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to add vgg16 layers to Sequential model but getting the error mentioned in the Question Title

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.models import Sequential
vgg_model = VGG16()
model = Sequential()
#print(model.summary())
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
        model.add(layer)

print(model.summary())
```

I am using keras 2.2.4

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7fc6f1b92240>
```

Comment: why would you need another model? can't you use vgg_model?

Comment: I have to use this model to classify 10 classes. Will add till 15 layers from vgg . But trying to add  the complete model to check but its not working.

Comment: You can use functional API for this.

Comment: Can you please help me with the snippet ? Also why its not working , Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to drop the last layer and add your own last full connected layer with 10, nodes. To achieve this keras functional API can be used.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.models import Sequential
import keras
from keras_applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vgg_model = VGG16()

# replace the last layer with new layer with 10 nodes.
last_layer = vgg_model.layers[-2].output ## 
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(last_layer) 

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs, outputs=output)
model.summary()


print(model.summary())
```

Or using include_top = False

```
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False)
vgg_output = vgg_model.outputs[0]
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(vgg_output)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs, outputs=output)
```

You may want to use pretrained weights. You can acheive this by using weights argument

```
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
```

You may want to freeze some of layers.

```
number_of_layers_to_freeze = 10
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False)
for i in range(number_of_layers_to_freeze):
    vgg_model.layers[i].trainable = False
vgg_output = vgg_model.outputs[0]
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(vgg_output)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_model.inputs, outputs=output)
```